# How can I load local images from a website?

Tags: http, web, localhost

I'm making a gallery site for a client, to be used for internal use. It is browsing hi-res images, so there's literally over 1 GB of images, each 3-4 MB, so loading the images through the web isn't an option due to load time.

My idea was to store the images on each machine locally, but maintain a central database online so all machines are in sync, and load the images using "file:///C:/images/file.jpg". But apparently browsers don't allow a website to load files from the local computer (for obvious security reasons).

How can I get around this?

Do I have to create a browser plugin myself to get access to the file system?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve my goal of (a) a centralized database of images and data, but (b) images stored locally?

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Comment: The local machines are Windows machines. I guess I can install WAMP Server, then serve the images through localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your images in your centralized database, but it would be of interest to also store smaller, resized images so that if the user is interested in the smaller version, s/he can click it, or hover over it, and have it load the larger version. 3-4MB isn't that insane for most computers to load, so long as the page isn't trying to load them all at once.

To get access to the file system, you can use the web-host's file access links, or you can use an FTP client, given that you know the FTP username/password.